# Как провести поиск по подстроке в массиве JavaScript, состоящем из строк?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, substring

Собственно, изучая JS поставил себе задачу (как оказалось, не по силам): сортировку email'ов по доменам из одного массива в разные массивы, каждый из которых соответствует определенным доменам.
Пробовал разные варианты от простых переборов массива, но если строку вытащить получается, то чаcть ее - никак. Смотрел разные варианты и сильно усложнил себе код - так, что сам перестаю понимать, что у меня происходит))
Текущая реализация кода выглядит так:

```
    const arrEmails = [
        'skg@mail.ru',
        'var1@mail.ru',
        'petya_19@bk.ru',
        'knz.arg@mail.ru',
        'john1978@gmail.com',
        'gondor.arr@yandex.ru',
        's.f.j@gmail.com',
        'helen.89@yandex.ru',
        'lordhw@gmail.com',
    ];

    const arrY = [];
    const arrM = [];
    const arrGM = [];

    function sortEmails() {
        for (i = 0; i < arrEmails; i++) {
            let pos = arrEmails.find((el) => typeof el === "string");
            if (pos.search('@mail.ru') === true || pos.search('@bk.ru') === true) {
                arrM.push(arrEmails[i]);
            } else {
                arrGM.push(arrEmails[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    sortEmails()
    console.log(arrY, arrM, arrGM)
```

Comment: А просто str.split по `@` на имя и домен, с последующей раскладкой по домену - не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути перед вами стоит задача группировки значений. Сначала определимся с форматом результата. Для каждого домена нам нужен список почт. Это можно выразить объектом, где ключ - строка, а значение - массив. Далее рассматриваем каждую почту. Если ее домен уже есть в нашей группировке - добавляем ее туда, если нет - создаем новую пару в конечном результате. Удобно это сделать через функцию reduce

```js
arrEmails.reduce((acc, email) => {
    const domain = email.split('@').pop();
    if (!acc[domain]) {
        acc[domain] = []
    }
    acc[domain].push(email)
    return acc
}, {})
```

```json
{
    "mail.ru": [
        "skg@mail.ru",
        "var1@mail.ru",
        "knz.arg@mail.ru"
    ],
    "bk.ru": [
        "petya_19@bk.ru"
    ],
    "gmail.com": [
        "john1978@gmail.com",
        "s.f.j@gmail.com",
        "lordhw@gmail.com"
    ],
    "yandex.ru": [
        "gondor.arr@yandex.ru",
        "helen.89@yandex.ru"
    ]
}
```

Выделить домен тут удобно разделением строки по символу @

Comment: да, вот я как раз попытался сделать поиск по подстроке, начиная с символа @, но  не догадался использовать split и распределить в качестве параметров функции части строк.
спасибо огромное!